# .net working with outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

i have such code

```
For Each objItem In StartFolder.Items                    
    MessageBox.Show("to " + objItem.To)
Next
```

if field to is empty(empty in letter of outlook), there is no exception but the debugger shows

> ```
>   objItem.To  Run-time exception thrown : System.MissingMemberException - Public member 'To' on type 'ReportItem' not found.
> ```

how can i catch this? because any try to check property  objItem.To will generate another exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what you are trying to do: You could test each item's type before attempting to access a property that does not exist for a particular type (in your post the item type in question is `ReportItem`).e.g.

```
For Each objItem In StartFolder.Items 
    '' I think you will need to fully qualify ReportItem with the full namespace...   
    if TypeOf obItem is ReportItem           
        MessageBox.Show("to " + objItem.To) 
Next
```

Comment: not exactly, look- i make loop in letters, some letters for example has field TO filled , so calling objItem.To works, but some letters don't have filled property TO , but this becaume knowing only when i try to access objItem.To, so i need somehow check property To

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a try...catch to specifically catch the System.MissingMemberException?